# Why does hIsEOF not return?

Tags: haskell, client-server, handle

I am creating a simple chat server using Haskell's `Network` library. The server has to do two things:

- Broadcast a message every ***n*** ticks to all of the currently connected clients
- Receive any messages from the clients sent to the server.

The server and client are defined as

```
data Server = Server {
  sSocket :: Socket,
  sPort :: Port,
  sClients :: MVar (Set.Set ClientAddress)
  }

newtype ClientAddress = ClientAddress (Handle, HostName, PortNumber) 
                          deriving (Show)
```

A server is constructed by running the following function

```
startServer :: Port -> IO ThreadId -- 
startServer port = withSocketsDo $ do
  socket  <- listenOn $ PortNumber $ fromIntegral port  
  clients <- newMVar Set.empty
  let server = Server socket port clients
  forkIO $ forever $ do
    client@(handle, host, port) <- accept socket
    modifyMVar_ clients (\cs -> return $ Set.insert (ClientAddress client) cs)
    forkIO $ forever $ serve $ ClientAddress client
  forkIO $ forever $ sendServerUpdates 1000000 server
```

Note that the last two lines fork two different threads: the first for handling client connections and "serving" their messages, and the second for sending server broadcasts to the clients.

Broadcasting to the clients works as follows

```
sendServerUpdates :: Microsecond -> Server -> IO ()
sendServerUpdates frequency server = do
  withMVar (sClients server) (mapM_ sendServerUpdate)
  threadDelay frequency

sendServerUpdate :: ClientAddress -> IO ()
sendServerUpdate (ClientAddress (handle, host, port)) = do
  putStrLn "Sending update."
```

---

The issue I have, is that receiving messages from the clients seem to block. I receive messages by checking if the handle has contents

```
serve :: ClientAddress -> IO ()
serve (ClientAddress (handle, host, port)) = do
  b <- hIsEOF handle
  putStrLn $ show $ b -- <-- It never makes it this far...
```

Unfortunately, the code never makes it to the second line to call the `putStrLn`. It seems like `hIsEOF` encounters some exception, [although the documentation doesn't seem to mention it](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/GHC-IO-Handle.html#v:hIsEOF).

Why does my code block on `hIsEOF` forever?

Comment: Can you catch and print out the exception?  You can use `Control.Exception.try` to do this using: `try (hIsEOF handle) :: IO (Either SomeException Bool)`

Comment: It doesn't make it past the try to allow me to print anything. If I put a print statement before `try ...` it shows, but not afterwards.

Comment: The documentation you linked does say "NOTE: hIsEOF may block, because it has to attempt to read from the stream to determine whether there is any more data to be read."

Comment: If the `try` blocks, then that means that it's not an exception.  `try` is designed to immediately return if there is an exception.  This suggests that @ØrjanJohansen is correct and it is blocking on reading from the stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `hIsEOF`'s [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/System-IO.html) I found the following:

> NOTE: hIsEOF may block, because it has to attempt to read from the
>   stream to determine whether there is any more data to be read.

I wouldn't have expected this. I wonder if `hReady` or `hGetBufNonBlocking` are any better? I've never tried the whole non-blocking IO bit in Haskell.

Comment: Thanks, the three of you were correct and it was blocking.